# Transição entre cliques no link href bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, transição

Gostaria que ao clicar nos conteúdos, ele sumisse suavemente e mostrasse o outro conteúdo.

Só que do jeito que estou fazendo, ele aparece, some e aparece.

```js
var codigo = 0;
$('.btn-news').on('click', function () {
    var news = $('.noticias');


   var id = $(this).data('id');
   codigo = id;


   switch (codigo){
       case 1:
           news.fadeOut();
           news.html('<p style="margin: 1rem 2rem"> Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente .</p>').fadeIn()
           break;
       case 2:
           news.fadeOut();
           news.html(

                    '<p style="margin: 1rem 2rem">É um fato conhecido de todos .</p>').fadeIn();
           break;

   }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
       <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
       
 </head>
<body> 
<div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1" ></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4" ><b>&Uacute;limas Not&iacute;cias</b></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-7" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
                            <div class="noticias">

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1" style="width: 1px;"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn-news">Noticia 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" data-id="2" class="btn-news">Noticia 2</a></li>
                               
                            </ul>


                        </div>
                    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar o tempo de transição fadeOut(1000);

Comment: mesmo assim continua aparecendo, sumindo e aparecendo

Comment: Aumente para 2000

Comment: O que é que, ao clicar, suma o texto e apareça o outro, só que ao clicar, o texto primeiro aparece, some e aparece novamente, aumentando o  fadeOut para 2000 ele apenas ficou um pouco mais lento, mas ainda assim continua o problema

Comment: Eu sugiro que você faça que a primeira div tenha a propriedade CSS "display" igual a "block", a segunda div tenha a propriedade CSS "display" igual a "none" e use a função "toggle()" do jQuery ao invés fadeIn() e fadeOut().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma.

Não sei se é boa prática, mas deu certo.

```js
$('.btn-news').on('click', function () {
        var news = $('.noticias');
        news.fadeOut();
        
       var id = $(this).data('id');
    


       switch (id){
           case 1:
               
               setTimeout(function (){
                       news.html('<p style="margin: 1rem 2rem"> Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente .</p>').fadeIn()
                },2000);
               
               break;
           case 2:
              setTimeout(function (){
               news.html(

                        '<p style="margin: 1rem 2rem">É um fato conhecido de todos .</p>').fadeIn()
                      },500);
               break;

       }
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
           <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
           
     </head>
    <body> 
    <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1" ></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4" ><b>&Uacute;limas Not&iacute;cias</b></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-7" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
                                <div class="noticias">

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-1" style="width: 1px;"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn-news">Noticia 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" data-id="2" class="btn-news">Noticia 2</a></li>
                                   
                                </ul>


                            </div>
                        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```